# Google Maps not working on my phone as virtual device

Tags: android, google-maps

I've just spent the last few hours setting up the Google Maps API v2. Now that I think that I have that done, I go to test things out and lo and behold, my app no longer runs on my phone. What did I do? Is it something that I did to offend Google Maps? I can see my phone in my list of Virtual Devices, and the VDK says that the device is valid. But when I run the app, nothing happens on my phone. I see no particular errors in the LogCat, so I don't know what I did. Here is my manifest.xml file in case some thing is wrong here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.my_app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- The following are all required to used Google Maps -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.my_app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.my_app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<!-- End Google maps requirements section -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >


    <activity
        android:name="com.example.my_app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MyEventsListActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".EventDetail"></activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms" />

    <!-- Remove this line once the maps are working -->
    <activity android:name=".MapTest"></activity>

    <!-- Google maps API key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxx"/>   
</application>

</manifest>
```

Anyone know what might have happened? Thanks!

EDIT: Based on some of the responses, I should clarify a couple of things. First of all, I am only using one machine. The SHA-1 fingerprint that I generated was generated on the exact same machine that I am developing on, so there is no issue there. Second, the phone that I am testing on was working just fine prior to my attempt to integrate maps into my application. This is why I suspect that somehow my attempt to use maps is conflicting with my phone.

What I'm wondering is whether the SHA-1 fingerprint is somehow not valid for my phone? If the fingerprint is only valid for one machine (which I believe it is), is my phone considered a *second machine*??? The phone is tethered to the computer via a USB cable and I'm running as a virtual device target. Any chance that this is the issue?

Thanks for the replies everybody.

RESOLUTION: I think that I figured this out. My phone is only running Android 2.3.4 (API 10). Since the v2 maps run on a minimum of API 11, my phone was not being recognized for that reason. I had to change the minSdkVersion to 10, and also add

to my application node. It seems to work, although I still don't get a map to display. I have the usual Google background and grid. But at least no errors and my app is not functioning again on my phone. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks again!

Comment: have you followed all necessary steps?and which device r u using?

Comment: show us some code.http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Answer (score 1):

The API key which you have created will work only on that particular machine..
If you compile and install the .apk from another machine Maps will not show up..

Comment: Because when we generate an API KEY for google maps v2, we need to provide SHA-1 fingerprint(Unique for each machine) and the package name.

Comment: To show up the maps from other machine we can only install the .apk file generated from the machine which is registered with Google.

Comment: This does not seem correct. SHA is generated from signing key (kept inside .keystore file) and you can sign APK using this key on any machine.

Comment: ".keystore file" generates different SHA-1 on different machines.. I had the same problem of not showing up the maps when i compiled the project from other machine and installed the app... I resolved it by following my logic.

Comment: Same .keystore file will generate same SHA-1 on different machines. Different keys will generate differnt SHA-1. The obvious thing to do is copy debug.keystore from one machine to all other.

Comment: Bingo! But that's just a different way of applying the same logic.. Your way is more convenient obviously.. Nice Talking mate..

Answer (score 0):

Because you changed the minSDK to 10, the reason it's not working is probably because you are using the wrong object for the map, make sure that you are using `SupportMapFragment` and `FragmentActivity` ( For fragment support in OS prior to API level 11 ).

Of-course you would need to add the `android-support-v4` library.

As already been suggested here follow this short 9 step blog post I wrote to integrate Google Maps in your application if you want to support OS lower then 11:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)